# Is there a way to get a unique hidden input of a row within a php loop? I only get the last value

Tags: php, html, mysql, button, hidden-field

I have a HTML table, with every row in the table there is a button. I am trying to retrieve the ID of the row the button was on.
However, the hidden field seems to be overridden each time it loops through, resulting in every button having the same hidden input.

I am using HTML and PHP with a mySql database. I do not want to use jQuery or any javascript.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitSearch'])){
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Image</th><th>Auction</th><th>Purchase</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($view->itemsDataSet as $itemsData) {

    echo '<tr> <td>' . $itemsData->getItemID() . '</td> <td>' . $itemsData->getItemTitle() . '
            
          </td> <td>' . $itemsData->getItemDescription() . '</td> <td>' . '<img  src="' . $itemsData->getItemImage() . '  " alt="no picture" />' .'</td> <td>' . $itemsData->getAuctionID() . '</td> </td>'. '<td>
          <input type="hidden" name="auction" id="itemID" value='.$itemsData->getItemTitle().' />
          <button type="submit" name="buy" value="submitBid">Bid</button></td> </tr>';


} ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: with multiple elements all of the same name the last one generated will be the one used. You need to use Javascript to access specific records or use a new form for each record

Comment: I agree with @ProfessorAbronsius, put form in every tr.

Comment: Note that a `form` tag must be contained inside an idividual `td` element.

Comment: Put the ID you need to submit into the value attribute of the button, remove the hidden input field, problem solved.

Comment: @El_Vanja having the form encompass the whole table, is also allowed. You just can not put the from “between” the table rows or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is that, my whole table is a form but, each row should be a form instead.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I know, I was just extending on the previous comment. My bad on being imprecise.

Comment: If you don’t need to submit any other info besides the ID here - then you can keep one single form going around the whole table, just put the ID into the value of the submit button then. (And remove the hidden input field.)

Answer (score 0):

> put form in every tr if you will redirect on button click. but if you
> want to do something with js you can just add a data-id in your button
> eg  in your loop td:

```
<button data-id="'.$itemsData->getItemTitle().'" class="btn_click">Click Me</button>
```

> so now if you use js you can add a click on "btn_click" class  and get
> its value by $(this).attr('data-id') inside button click function and
> do waht ever you want.

> if you have to submit form on button click use form

```
<form method="" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="auction" id="itemID" value='.$itemsData->getItemTitle().' />
          <button type="submit" name="buy" value="submitBid">Bid</button>
</form></td>
```

Comment: sorry, but I am not using any js

Comment: okay so u have to create form in every tr

Comment: yes, I originally had the whole table as a form, but now each row is a from thanks